# Непонятная ошибка в SQL запросе(ВОПРОС РЕШЁН!)

Tags: mysql

у меня есть SQL запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE  `moderators` (
`id` varchar(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`serverid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`moderators` text,
`jailmoderators` text
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

И данный запрос выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251' at line 6
```

Я проверял этот код на сайте проверки синтаксиса, и он показал, что всё хорошо. Не подскажете, в чём может быть проблема?

P.S. ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА ОТВЕТЫ! Я РАЗОБРАЛСЯ!

Answer (score 1):

Я СЛУЧАЙНО заметил, что вы пропустили запятую перед `PRIMARY KEY`, что конечно же является синтаксической ошибкой.

Кроме того, в приведенном примере запроса ошибка в типе данных `varchar` для `autoincrement`. Но если этот запрос выполнить, то ошибка будет *другая*,

> Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

то есть корректный запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
CREATE TABLE `moderators` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`serverid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`moderators` TEXT NULL,
`jailmoderators` TEXT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: зачем так пробовать?

Comment: @Ипатьев Может потому, что у автора AI на varchar сидит? Что значит зачем?

Comment: а какое отношение неверный тип поля для автоинкремента имеет к ошибкам синтаксиса? Нет, ты конечно исправил ошибку в своем ответе -видимо случайно - но ответ без объяснения никому не нужен. Особенно если вопрос бессмысленный сам по себе

Comment: @Ипатьев Исправил, благодарю за конструктивную критику

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За что минусуем? За то что я не сказал вам проверить еще codepage которого у вас скорее всего не установлено?

Answer (score -1):

Так varchar или autoicrement. В общем вы ошиблись в описании колонки id

Comment: Извините, можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? Тип колонки varchar, это авто инкремент. Ставил int, ошибка та же

Comment: И я ещё написал, что проверял код на сайте проверки синтаксиса. И мне никакой ошибки не выдало

Comment: @MihlanDOta какой ещё сайт проверки синтаксиса? У тебя в запросе ошибка на ошибке и ошибокой погоняет. то есть либо сайт тупой, либо ты не можешь собраться с мыслями и решить, какой именно запрос ты проверяешь, какой выполняешь, а какой пишешь на стаковерфлой. потому что это похоже три разных запроса